# Why are the words for "heavens" and "waters" so similar?

Tags: words, hebrew, genesis-bereishith

Genesis 1:9 mentions waters and heavens: "הַמַּ֜יִם מִתַּ֤חַת הַשָּׁמַ֨יִם֙".

The words "mayim" (waters) and "shamayim" (heavens) are very similar.

Is this a coincidence, or is there some underlying connection between these two words (and concepts)?

Comment: Check out the previous verses

Answer (score 5):

The Talmud gives an answer:

> It was taught in a baraita: Shamayim means esh umayim, [fire and water], which teaches that the Holy One, Blessed be He, brought them and combined them together, and made the heavens from them. [Chagigah 12a]